# Memory size exhausted issue when sending more than 2mb file as attachment in php

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer version 6.* and PHP 7. When I attach a file which is more than 2 mb and try to send an email, it is giving following error (Before I was using lower version of PHPMailer with PHP5. It was working fine in this case.)

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 20971520 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 18840168 bytes) in
>   /var/www/html/email/classes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php on line 3027

I have increased memory limit and execution time in php.ini but issue remains same.

Answer (score 2):

Encoding attachments in PHPMailer is indeed memory-hungry, mainly because it holds the whole attachment and a line-by-line array of the content in memory. Ideally this would be converted to using a generator (which will be much more memory efficient), but that will have to wait for the next BC break.

In the mean time, increase your memory allocation further - it's not uncommon for defaults to be set at 64M or 128M, rather than the 20M you've given it.

Comment: I have already increased memory allocation to 128M and also increased execution time to 120s. But it throws same error.

Comment: I had this issue too and had 128M. Increase memory limit to 200M it was ok.
Execution time is not important.